# onClickListener using Butterknife

Tags: java, android, butterknife

**onClickListener using Butterknife is bit confusing**

Say, I have a Whatsapp button which onClick opens Whatsapp to share something. By conventional means, the code for onClickListener would be something like

```
ImageButton buttonWhatsapp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.whatsapp);

buttonWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
optionsShareThis.whatsApp(ActivityWebView.this, ShareThisURL);
    }
});
```

where, `optionsShareThis` is an object of `OptionsShareThis` class and `whatsApp(Context context, String Url)` is a method defined in this class.

I am confused with how to define onClick event using Butterknife. I tried using

`@Bind(R.id.whatsapp) ImageButton ButtonWhatsapp;` to bind the View

Then the below code for onClick event

```
@OnClick(R.id.whatsapp) void onClick() {
    optionsShareThis.whatsApp(this, ShareThisURL);
}
```

Android Studio says the field `ButtonWhatsapp` and the method `onClick()` *is never used*. What's happening?

**EDIT:**  I have already added `Butterknife.bind(this)` inside `onCreate()`. Sorry, I didn't mention this earlier

Comment: just add ButterKnife.bind(this); in OnCreate() method after setContentView() method.

Comment: its bind all butterknife object with your xml and your activity.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `ButterKnife.bind(this);` inside the `onCreate` of your activity and then

```
@OnClick(R.id.whatsapp) 
public void onClick() {
    optionsShareThis.whatsApp(this, ShareThisURL);
}
```

outside of `onCreate` method anywhere

You don't have to add this line `@Bind(R.id.whatsapp) ImageButton ButtonWhatsapp;`

Comment: I am sorry. I have already added Butterknife.bind(this), inside onCreate

Comment: Thanks for the second suggestion however. Not requiring @Bind(R.id.whatsapp) makes sense.

Comment: Android Studio says `public void onClick() {
        optionsShareThis.whatsApp(this, ShareThisURL);` is never used

Comment: Run/Debug it once, the warning will go

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but since the most up-voted answer does not resolve this, I am answering it. Its a simple miss.

**You forgot to pass view as parameter to your method.**

```
@OnClick(R.id.whatsapp) 
public void onClick(View view) {
    optionsShareThis.whatsApp(this, ShareThisURL);
}
```

Hope this works for future help seekers.

Answer (score 0):

As Nongthonbam Tonthoi said in a comment, building/running the app should remove the warning and as shown in previous answers onClick() should be public. I was seeing the same warning until I built the project but the code below works for me.

```
@OnClick(R.id.ingredients_btn)
public void onClick() {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.recipe_detail_container,
                    IngredientFragment.newInstance(mIngredients))
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you don't build project yet

`@OnClick` is annotation, that means the code is generated when you build your project

just `Build -> Rebuild Project`